# etoc and memoir compatibility isuues

Tags: memoir, incompatibility, etoc

I was just doing some test with the [`etoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) package and as soon as I changed the document class from `book` to `memoir`, errors appeared. This simple document

```
%\documentclass{book}
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{A test chapter}

\end{document}
```

triggers the error message

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \if@cftnctoc 
                        \else \renewcommand *\etocstandarddisplaystyle {\eto...
l.1150      }
```

which indicates that `\if@cftnctoc` is not defined. I checked the code for `etoc` and in lines 1106 to 1124 (one can also see this in the page 88 of the package documentation), there are two uses of this command, but I couldn't figure out what the problem really was. The `etoc` documentation mentions that the package is compatible with `memoir`, so I am lost. Am I missing something?

Edit: this appears in the *Foreword* of `etoc`'s documentation:

> `etoc` appears to be (at least partially) compatible with the `article`,
>   `book`, `report`, `scrartcl`, `scrbook`, `scrreprt` and `memoir` classes.
>   Starting with release 1.07k it is possible to use `etoc` concurrently
>   with package `tocloft`.

Comment: The `memoir` class emulates `tocloft` (with differences) and, in order to avoid users load it, fakes it being loaded, so `etoc` gets confused. Unfortunately, `\DisemulatePackage{tocloft}` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `memoir` class emulates `tocloft` (with differences) and, in order to avoid users load it, fakes it being loaded, so `etoc` gets confused. In particular, `tocloft` defines

```
\newif\if@cftnctoc\@cftnctocfalse
\DeclareOption{titles}{\@cftnctoctrue}
```

So the conditional seems to be used only for the `titles` option, which has no meaning for `memoir`. My suggestion is to file a bug report and do

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\let\if@cftnctoc\iftrue
\makeatother
\usepackage{etoc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*
\chapter{A test chapter}

\end{document}
```

The `titles` option in `tocloft` makes it not override the code for chapter titles in the table of contents or similar lists, so I guess setting it to true is the right thing to do with `memoir`.